# python y cx_oracle, no se me ejecuta el codigo desde python, porque?

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.7, pycharm

Desde pycharm cuando lo ejecuto, me va bien, pero cuando abro el programa desde Python
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se me abre Python y se cierra rápidamente, no debería hacer eso, me debería de correr normal para que el usuaria introduzca cosas, no? esto es lo que debería de salir.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se abre la venta y rápidamente se cierra.
Tengo que decir que estoy trabajando con cx_oracle y realizo varias consultas
os dejo imagen de todas ficheros .py que utilizo y importo cx_oracle[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay algun error o es eso lo que deberia de realizar?
si alguien le interesa el codigo, dejo el enlace siguiente donde podréis descargar los 5 archivos (.py),esta con comentarios, tengo que decir que debéis tener instalado un "Oracle instant client"
enlace: [descarga porgrama](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fradEdxHoafW_o9JjC_8BDBi963fyaDf/view?usp=sharing)

Si descargáis el programa, va sobre la gestion de los vuelos de un aeropuerto. (ORY) es el codigo del aeropuerto de Paris Orly, os recomiendo no poner el de Barcelona (BCN) ya que tarda bastante en cargar los vuelos en la primera entrada por el usuario.

Comment: Hola, en lugar de colocar screenshots del codigo deberías colocar el codigo en texto, ya que en imagenes es muy dificil que te podamos ayudar, veo que no eres un usuario nuevo en el sitio, te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: el codigo es muy largo, os dejo un link si lo queréis ver y probar